# building from xcode source, missing "pods" library

Tags: xcode, build, codenameone

Attempting to build an ios project downloaded from the
build server, I get a link error complaining that the
"pods-develop" library was not found.  There's also a
pods xcode project, but building it doesn't change the
outcome.

What information am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have these **hints** in your Codename One propertie's build hint ?

```
ios.pods.sources=,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
ios.objC=true
```

Comment: It seems odd that I have to add this property.  The "include sources" checkbox ought to be all that's required.

Comment: You now need to open the xworkspace project and not the regular project. The workspace includes everything. This is related to the pods change which is ultimately a good change as it allows for faster/smaller and more up to date builds