# can't find the dossier pods and Podfile.lock

Tags: codenameone

The problem is when I downloaded the ios sources from the build server I can't find the dossier pods and Podfile.lock, in the previous day's everything was fine.

Do I have to change something in codenameone_settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39974694/756809

Comment: My Codename One propertie's build hin it contains: ios.pods.sources=,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
ios.objC=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When crossing a threshold of size pod libraries are stripped out to avoid huge download sizes. It's possible that one of the pods used grew too much and crossed that threshold.

You can fix this by running `pod install` in the command line.